# How to retrieve data of the fastest athlete for the activity walking?

Tags: mysql

I have to tables, 1 called "athelete" and table 2 called "training_session". First table consist of Id, names, email etc and the second contains activity and how long they have trained..

Athlete table

[image: Athlete table 1]

Training session table

[image: Training session table 2]

I want to retrieve data of the fastest athlete for the activity walking, and retrieve his/her id, speed, name and club code, i dont know how to approch this task.

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name, 
    a.club_code, 
    t.distance / t.duration speed,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.distance / t.duration DESC) rn
FROM 
   athlete a
   INNER JOIN training_session t ON a.id = t.athelete_id
WHERE t.activity = 'Walking'
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0n you can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to rank the walking training sessions by decreasing speed, and filter on the fastest session in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.name, 
        a.club_code, 
        t.distance / t.duration speed,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.distance / t.duration DESC) rn
    FROM 
       athlete a
       INNER JOIN training_session t ON a.id = t.athlete_id
    WHERE t.activity = 'Walking'
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

In earlier versions, you can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to ensure that there is no fastest walking session than the current one:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name, 
    a.club_code, 
    t.distance / t.duration speed,
FROM 
   athlete a
   INNER JOIN training_session t ON a.id = t.athlete_id
WHERE 
    t.activity = 'Walking'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM training_session t1
        WHERE 
            t1.distance / t1.duration > t.distance / t.duration
            AND t1.activity = 'Walking'
    )
```

Comment: I do get a error code, but you've helped me a lot :)

Comment: #1146 - Table 'trlog.athletes' doesn't exist, which is true.  'trlog.athletes' is the name of my database, not a table :) but i have no idea why that comes up

Comment: @Lilly: from you question it looks like table name is `athlete`, without `s` at the end. I modified the query.